# list contains for structure data type in DMN decision table

Tags: drools, kie, dmn, kogito, feel-language

I am planning to use [Drools](https://www.drools.org/learn/dmn.html) for executing the DMN models. However I am having trouble to write a condition in DMN **Decision table** where the input is an array of objects with structure data type and condition is to check if the array contains an object with specific fields. For ex:
Input to decision table is as below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "lastname": "pqr"
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "lastname": "lmn"
  },
  {
    "name": "pqr",
    "lastname": "jkl"
  }
]
```

Expected output: True if the above list contains an element that match {"name": "abc", "lastname": "pqr"} both on the same element in the list.

I see that FEEL has support for list contains, but I could not find a syntax where objects in array are not of primitive types like number,string etc but structures. So, I need help on writing this condition in Decision table.

Thanks!

---

Edited description:

I am trying to achieve the following using the decision table[image] wherein **details** is list of info structure. Unfortunately as you see I am not getting the desired output wherein my input list contains the specific element I am looking for.

Input: details = [{"name": "hello", "lastname": "world"}]

Expected Output = "Hello world" based on condition match in row 1 of the decision table.

Actual Output = null

NOTE: Also in row no 2 of the decision table, I only check for condition wherein I am only interested in the checking for the name field.

Content for the DMN file can be found over [here](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/Myr3wY99)

Answer (score 3):

In DMN, there are multiple ways to achieve the same result.

If I understand the real goal of your use case, I want to suggest a better approach, much easier to maintain from a design point of view.

First of all, you have a list of users as input so those are the data types:

[image: Data types]

Then, you have to structure a bit your decision:

[image: DG]

The decision node `at least one user match` will go trough the user list and will check if there is at least one user that matches the conditions inside the `matching` BKM.

`at least one user match` can implemented with the following FEEL expression:

```
some user in users satisfies matching(user)
```

The great benefit of this approach is that you can reason on specific element of your list inside the `matching` BKM, which makes the matching decision table extremely straightforward:

[image: decisin table]

Answer (score 2):

In this question is not clear the overall need and requirements for the Decision Table.

For what pertaining ***the part of the question*** about:

> True if the above list contains an element that match {"name": "abc", "lastname": "pqr"}
> ...
> I see that FEEL has support for list contains, but I could not find a syntax where objects in array are not of primitive types like number,string etc but structures.

This can be indeed achieved with the `list contains()` function, [described here](https://kiegroup.github.io/dmn-feel-handbook/#list-contains-list-element).

Example expression

```
list contains(my list, {"name": "abc", "lastname": "pqr"})
```

where `my list` is the verbatim FEEL list from the original question statement.

Example run:

[image]

giving the expected output, `true`.

Naturally 2 context (complex structures) are the same if all their properties and fields are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated the description of the problem. Let me know if that helps. Thanks!